# Download pdf file from php

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to make a file that send a pdf file to the visitor.
I have file: download.php

and this is his content:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$_GET['file']);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_GET['file']);
```

for some reason, the file sending an empty pdf file 183 bytes.

any advice?

thanks.

Comment: please post the value of $_GET['file']

Comment: I am using same code to send pdf for download except in readfile part i use absolute url to the file. So most likely your path is not correct.

Comment: Well, assuming that your pdf file is in the exact same location as the php script and the path given in `$_GET['file]` is correct, everything should work fine. Have you checked this two factors?

Comment: well yeah, I check the file, if I doing header("Location: ".$_GET['file']); so it's working... but he open the file and not download...

Comment: did you try using the exact same example as the one on the man page for readfile? http://php.net/readfile you might need to add the Content-Length header.. just add all those lines and if it works try to remove/change them one by one

Comment: @Hanan `header("Location: ".$_GET['file']);` and `readfile($_GET['file'])` are not the same. I think Peter's answer is correct

Comment: Solve for me, I post my solution in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538786/php-download-pdf-always-results-in-not-supported-file-type-of-damaged-file/16559853#16559853

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the full path to the file for readfile() not just a filename.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I actually just created script for PDF download, using Hanan's approach (although filename is read from DB, while document ID is received from $_GET['id'] so there's no security risk) and your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really should first check if the file exists with [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Second ... this seems pretty insecure since you allow specifying the filename through a global $_GET parameter. What if I would try to download your config file like `download.php?file=../application/settings/config.ini`? You should first filter the $_GET parameter and make sure the file specified is allowed for being downloaded.

Comment: yeah I will do that... and with the file_exists I getting "true" so the file is exists.. but downloading empty files...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header('Pragma: public');  // required
header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($filepath)) . ' GMT');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $pathinfo['filename'] . '.pdf');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath)); // provide file size
header('Connection: close');
readfile($filepath);
exit();
```